# button background not transparent， Embed external application inside Winforms Application

Tags: c#, .net

I take the external application window into the middle layer(a c# windows form application) by SetParent(hwnd, hwnd), but the button on the upper layer is not transparent, here is the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYbTp.png,)

is there any way to take it normal display?
this is code :

```
                mPPtRunHwnd = hWnd;
                CommonUtil.SetParent(mPPtRunHwnd, this.panel1.Handle);
                long style = CommonUtil.GetWindowLong(mPPtRunHwnd, CommonUtil.GWL_STYLE);
                style = style & ~((int)CommonUtil.WS_CAPTION) & ~((int)CommonUtil.WS_THICKFRAME) & ~CommonUtil.WS_POPUP; // Removes Caption bar and the sizing border
                style |= ((int)CommonUtil.WS_CHILD)| CommonUtil.WS_EX_LAYERED | CommonUtil.WS_VISIBLE; // Must be a child window to be hosted

                CommonUtil.SetWindowLong(mPPtRunHwnd, CommonUtil.GWL_STYLE, style);

                CommonUtil.SetWindowPos(mPPtRunHwnd, CommonUtil.HWND_TOP, 100, 100, (int)500, (int)500, 0);

                CommonUtil.ShowWindow(mPPtRunHwnd, CommonUtil.SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/building-transparent-controls-in-wpf

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683): "it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws. ... I often see this question in the context of somebody who wants to grab a window belonging to another process and forcibly graft it into their own process ... things will definitely stop working if you change that other window from a top-level window to a child window"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Robert Harvey, but my application is a winform app， and the problem is the middle panel embed the ppt， and the button on  the upper cannot transparent， and the button get the backcolor of the panel but not ppt